# Configure tns to look in different directory for transpiled JavaScript in NativeScript build from TypeScript?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

`tns` appears to require that TypeScript be transpiled to JavaScript files in the same source directory for its build process to work. Is it possible to configure `tns` to look in a different directory for its JavaScript?

I am trying to share code with another build process and keeping the transpiled JavaScript separate would be extremely useful. I can simply add an `outDir` property to the project's `tsconfig.json` to have `tsc` transpile to a different output directory, but I don't know how to point `tns` to this location.